# Define a function isVowel(char) that returns True if char is a vowel ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', or 'u'), and False otherwise

Tags: python

**Question:**

Define a function isVowel(char) that returns True if char is a vowel ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', or 'u'), and False otherwise. You can assume that char is a single letter of any case (ie, 'A' and 'a' are both valid).

Do not use the keyword in. Your function should take in a single string and return a boolean.

**Code Given:**

```
def isVowel(char):
    '''
    char: a single letter of any case

    returns: True if char is a vowel and False otherwise.
    '''
```

**My Code:**

```
def isVowel(char):
    '''
    char: a single letter of any case

    returns: True if char is a vowel and False otherwise.
    '''
    if char == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u' or 'A' or 'E' or 'I' or 'O' or 'U':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**My Problem:**
My output is always True. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sigh, will teachers ever stop creating tasks that require you to write bad code that nobody knowing the language would ever write?

Comment: @ThiefMaster. May be they want to teach some basics first. But, unfortunately they have chosen wrong problem for this `==` operator.

Comment: **"Do not use the keyword in"**. What they are trying to teach, how to be a stupid coder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your if statement:

```
if char == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u' or 'A' or 'E' or 'I' or 'O' or 'U':
        return True
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (char == 'a') or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u' or 'A' or 'E' or 'I' or 'O' or 'U':
```

which will always be evaluated to either `True`, or `e` which is also `True`, and hence your function always returns `True`.

Change your if-statement to:

```
if char == 'a' or char == 'e' or char == 'i' so on...:
        return True
```

---

But, this problem is really simple if you can use `in` operator. This goes like this:

```
def isVowel(char):
    return char.lower() in 'aeiou'
```

Comment: they don't actually need the if statement, just `return char == 'a' or char == etc`.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't read like English. You'd expect your code to work, but it's evaluated like this:

```
if (char == 'a') or ('b') or ('c') ...
```

`'a'` is truthy (not `False`, `0`, `None`, etc.), so your `if` statement will always evaluate to `True`.

To fix your code, you have to write *exactly* what you mean:

```
if char == 'a' or char == 'b' or ...
```

Or just use `in`:

```
if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is how you are supposed to do it without stupid restrictions:

```
def is_vowel(char):
    return char.lower() in 'aeiou'
```

Since you cannot use the `in` operator. I assume the `in` from the loop is allowed:

```
def is_vowel(char):
    char = char.lower()
    return any(char == c for c in 'aeiou')
```

If that's still a no-go, here's something that is not really nice but differs from the `or` chain in the other answers:

```
def is_vowel(char):
    return is_in_list(char.lower(), 'aeiou')

def is_in_list(char, lst):
    if not lst:
        return False
    if char == lst[0]:
        return True
    return is_in_list(char, lst[1:])
```

Last but not least, you can avoid using the `in` operator while still using its functionality:

```
def is_vowel(char):
    return 'aeiou'.__contains__(char.lower())
```

Obviously this is most likely not what your professor/teacher expects - but it would show him that you are smart (or he already saw this post and will know you didn't do your homework on your own).

Comment: You could use `'aeiou'.__contains__(char.lower())` to get around the `in` restriction.

Comment: @Blender. I guess if `in` is not allowed, then sure `OP` wouldn't know about this method too.

Comment: @ThiefMaster.. haha. The last line. ROFL. And what if teacher came here to get a better solution himself? ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_vowel(char):
    try:
            'aeiou'.index(char.lower())
            return True
    except: 
            return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_vowel(char):
    return False if 'aeiouAEIOU'.find(char) < 0 else True
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Xcode on my Mac, but I think the results should be the same.

```
//Program: Vowels      
#include < iostream >
#include < cctype >

using namespace std;

bool isVowel (char ch);

int main()    
{
    char ch;

    cout << "Enter a letter and I will tell you if it is a vowel: \n" ;      
    cin >> ch;      
    cout << isVowel(ch) << endl;
}

bool isVowel(char ch)    
{       
    ch= tolower(ch);
    if (ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def vowel(char):
    if char.lower() in 'aeiou':
        return True
    if char.upper() in 'AEIOU':
        return TRUE
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: The OP has this requirement: "*Do not use the keyword in*". Though, I would say using `in` would have been the better solution.